# How to update a div content using jquery in cakephp2.1

Tags: jquery, cakephp, load

so i want to click a button an update a controller'action within a div,like this:

```
$('.navMenuButton').click(function(){
    $('#workarea').load('/controller/action');
})
```

can i do that in cakephp using jquery load() method,how?
By the way ,the cakephp'2.x document hasn,t been very helpful about the jshelper,can someone suggest somebook or just tell me how to use the jshelper! thanx!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

You want to stop cake using your page layout template and just return the view.

You can either include the RequestHandler component or set the layout to ajax in your view:

```
$this->layout = "ajax";
```